# How to specify the namespace while creating XML using python (lxml)

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to create XML file using python. I want to create a XML file similar to below one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<toplevel>
  <ChildLevel
    xmlns=http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/environment/1>
    <Property key="username1" value="test"/>
    <Property key="username2" value="testuser"/>
  </ChildLevel>
</toplevel>
```

I have written the below python script and generate the XML file. But how do I can specify the namespace while creating xml file.

```
from lxml import etree
from array import array

val_ = []
val_.append("username1## test ")
val_.append("username2## testuser ")
xml__= etree.Element('toplevel')

product_=etree.SubElement(ovf_env_xml, " ChildLevel")

for keyval_ in val_:
    keyvalue_ = keyval_.split("##")
    property_ = etree.SubElement(product_, 'Property')
    property_.set("key", keyvalue_[0])
    property_.set("value", keyvalue_[1])

etree.ElementTree(xml__).write("/tmp/test.xml", pretty_print=True)
```

**Output XML File:**

```
<toplevel>
  <ChildLevel>
    <Property key="username1" value="test"/>
    <Property key="username2" value="testuser"/>
  </ChildLevel>
</toplevel
```

I need to append the multiple namespace in my XML file.

---

---

sorry guys.. i got the solution after searching few more blogs.. i just done the below changes in my python script.

```
 nsmap = {
         None: "urn:iso:std:iso:2013:008.001.02",
         'xsi': "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
     }

    xml__= etree.Element('toplevel',nsmap=nsmap)
```

Comment: sorry guys.. i got the solution after searching few more blogs.. i just done the below changes in my python script.

    nsmap = {
         None: "urn:iso:std:iso:2013:008.001.02",
         'xsi': "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
     }
    
    xml__= etree.Element('toplevel',nsmap=nsmap)